# SSRS - declare template area in the report

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS in Visual Studio 2010.

Many of the reports have fixed area, which is repeated at each report.

How can I add a reference to the fixed area (that may be a template for all the reports)? (Landscape/Portrait reports).

If there is no way doing above - What is the best way to solve the problem of repeated part at every report?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/creating-a-custom-report-template-in-ssrs.html) is a link on creating ssrs templates for VS projects. I picked the first search result, it looked thorough.